# Calculation in model failing for rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, rake-task

I have a method/action/piece of code (I always get a bit lost on the terminology of rails) set up in my model to update the amount remaining in a budget when I input a new advert.

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :client
has_many :adverts
before_save :update_budget

validates :name, :amount, :client_id, presence: true

def update_budget
    self.amount_remaining = self.amount - self.amount_spent
end
end
```

This works fine when updating my budgets or entering a new advert. Everything works as it should. However, I have written a rake task to write a list of recurring budgets to the budget table (so I can schedule it monthly). However, when I run this task from the terminal it runs into an error.

The rake task.

```
desc "Recurring Updates"
task :recurring_budgets => :environment do
    @recurring_budgets = RecurringBudget.all
    @recurring_budgets.each do |recurring_budget|
        Budget.create(name: recurring_budget.name, amount: recurring_budget.amount, client_id: recurring_budget.client_id)
    end
end
```

The error.

```
$ rake recurring_budgets
rake aborted!
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
/Users/tomgamon/projects/adsman/app/models/budget.rb:9:in `-'
/Users/tomgamon/projects/adsman/app/models/budget.rb:9:in `update_budget'
/Users/tomgamon/projects/adsman/lib/tasks/recurring_budgets.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/tomgamon/projects/adsman/lib/tasks/recurring_budgets.rake:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => recurring_budgets
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Worth noting is when I remove the method from my model, the task writes to the budgets table fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to you were trying to `minus` `nil` from `amount`

`update_budget` called in `before_save callback` - and here you calculating `amount_remaining` with subtracting `amount_spent` from `amount` in your case `amount_spent` is `nil`, so when you try subtracting `nil` value from something then you will get this error - `TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`

There are two solutions for this -

1 - if `amount_spent` is `nil` you have to use `0`

```
def update_budget
    self.amount_remaining = self.amount - (self.amount_spent || 0)
end
```

**OR**

2 - you can set default values for `amount_remaining`, `amount`and `amount_spent` as `0`(Zero) in migration.

***It will be better to set default values for such fields instead of checking `nil` values in code.***

Comment: Brilliant. I have added the default values into my table and it is working perfectly now. Thanks!